# What is set here? (noun or past participle)

Tags: prepositional-phrases

> Are you tired of taking pictures with your camera **set** to “Auto”? Do you want to create more professional-looking photos? You won’t want to miss this opportunity.

"set" is used as a noun as well as a verb.
I wonder if the "set" described above is a noun or a past participle

Comment: "Set" is a past participle verb. "Your camera set to Auto” is a clause where "your camera" is subject and the verb phrase "set to auto" is predicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A digital camera comes with a set of predefined modes. One of them is usually **the auto (=automatic) mode**, which seeks a fine balance across all the settings.

> ... with your camera **which is configured to use the “Auto” mode**?

> ... with your camera **which is set (up) to be in (the) “Auto” mode**?

*set* here is the past participle of the verb *set*.